# Two inner join with Condition not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tbl_family

```
#ID Name    Gender
1   Ram M         
2   Sasank  M         
3   Maya    F         
4   Manu    F         
5   Anu F         
6   Raj M
```

tbl_childparent

```
#Child_id   Parent_id
1   2
1   3
4   5
4   6
```

I want a output which needs to display ChildID,ChildName,Father,Mother 
This is my sql query but it doesn't work

```
SELECT tf2.ID,tf2.Name AS ChildName,tf.Name AS Father,tf3.Name AS Mother 
FROM dbo.tbl_clildparent tc
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Family tf ON tc.Parent_id=tf.ID 
    AND tf.Gender='M'
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Family tf3 ON tc.Parent_id = tf3.ID 
    AND tf3.Gender='F'
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl_Family tf2 ON tc.Child_id = tf2.ID
```

Comment: How do we know _which_ mother or father belongs to which child?  I don't see this relationship in your data.

Comment: Cheque the tbl_child parent table it shows child id and parentid and based on gender we need to get father and mother

Comment: Is this possible to have two parents (father & Mother) records for one child?

Comment: @RCY show your expected output

Comment: @Chanukya my query doesnot show expected output if I remove one inner join then it shows only father or mother name not both..

Comment: ID ChildName Father Mother
1 Ram                Sasank   NULL
4 Manu           Raj           NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query

```
SELECT  Child_id,N.Name,
        MAX((CASE WHEN F.Gender = 'M' THEN F.Name ELSE NULL END )) AS Father,
        MAX((CASE WHEN M.Gender = 'F' THEN M.Name ELSE NULL END )) AS Mother
FROM    @tbl_childparent    AS  C
    INNER JOIN  @Tbl_family AS  N   ON  N.ID    =   C.Child_id
    LEFT JOIN @Tbl_family   AS  F   ON  F.ID    =   C.Parent_id
    LEFT JOIN @Tbl_family   AS  M   ON  M.ID    =   C.Parent_id
GROUP BY Child_id,N.Name
```

OUTPUT:

```
Child_id    Name    Father  Mother
1           Ram     Sasank  Maya
4           Manu    Raj     Anu
```

Comment: Thanks.. but why was my code not working when I used two inner join

Comment: in your query joining a tc.Parent_id to tbl_Family with different condition (both 'M' and 'F'). if the both conditions are satisfied then only you will get result, here it will not happen.

Comment: Do one-thing, just change all your INNER joins to LEFT OUTER JOINs in your query, you will get a better understanding now.

Answer (score 2):

**TRY THIS:** you can achieve desired output using `CASE` and `GROUP BY` as below:

```
select tf.id AS ChildID, tf.Ename AS ChildName, 
    Max(case when tfp.gender = 'm' then tfp.Ename end) Father, 
    MAX(case when tfp.gender = 'f' then tfp.Ename end) Mother
from #tbl_childparent tc
left join #tbl_Family tf on tc.child_id = tf.id
left join #tbl_Family tfp on tc.parent_id = tfp.id
group by tf.id, tf.Ename
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ChildID ChildName   Father  Mother
4       Manu        Raj     Anu 
1       Ram         Sasank  Maya
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id,ChildName,
MAX(CASE WHEN Gender='M' THEN Father END)Father,
MAX(CASE WHEN Gender='F' THEN Mother END)Mother 
FROM (
SELECT tf2.ID,tf2.Name AS ChildName,tf.Name AS Father,tf.Name AS Mother,tf.Gender
FROM #TEMP1 tc
INNER JOIN #TEMP tf ON tc.Parentid=tf.ID 
LEFT JOIN #TEMP tf2 ON tc.Childid = tf2.ID
)A GROUP BY Id,ChildName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
(
select cp.Child_ID, c.Name as 'ChildName' 
cp.Parent_ID, p.Name as 'ParentName', p.Gender as 'ParentGender'
from tbl_childparent cp
join Tbl_family p on cp.Parent_ID = p.ID
join Tbl_family c on cp.Child_ID = c.ID
)

select t1.CHildID, t1.ChildName, t1.ParentName as Father, t2.ParentName as Mother from cte t1
join cte t2 on t1.child_id = t2.child_ID
where t1.ParentGender = M and t2.ParentGender = 'F'
```